# Hola! ¿Cómo puedo usar onmouseover/onmouseout y cambiar la barra de estado?

Tags: java, script, href

Necesito que al pasar el ratón por encima de un hipervinculo aparezca un texto en la barra de estado y al quitar el ratón que salga un texto diferente. Debo usar los manejadores onmouseover y onmouseout y solo puedo usar una función. Necesito ayuda, no se como conseguir el efecto. Esto es lo que he escrito y tampoco funciona.
¿Alguién sabría como solucionarl?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Practica4</title>
</head>
<body>  
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var enlace = document.getElementsByTagName("Enlace")[0];
        function cambiar1(){
            window.status= "Por encima del hipervinculo...";
        }
        function cambiar2(){
            window.status= "Fuera del hipervinculo...";
        }

        enlace.onmouseover = cambiar1
        enlace.onmouseout = cambiar2

    </script>

    <a href="Gato.html" name="Enlace" id="Enlace">Hipervínculo</a> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: has escuchado hablar de Jquery? es una buena opción a la hora de crear tales efectos, ya que no tiene ningún problema de compatibilidad en los navegadores y puedes crear dicho efecto en pocas lineas de códigos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bueno primero que todo te aconsejo que en el tag a no utilices el atributo name, pues este ya es obsoleto en html5, ya se utiliza el atributo global id en su lugar.Por otra parte window.status se ha deshabilitado en la mayoría de los navegadores (si no en todos) por razones de seguridad (era posible falsificar una ubicación diferente para los enlaces de esa manera).Y bueno pues ... utilizando el ID y arrow function el código  a mi parecer te quedaría mejor, de esta forma:

```
  <a href="Gato.html" id="Enlace" >Hipervínculo</a> 

   <script type="text/javascript">
      var enlace = document.getElementById("Enlace");
      enlace.onmouseover =()=> window.status= "Por encima del hipervinculo...";
      enlace.onmouseout =()=> window.status= "Fuera del hipervinculo...";

  </script>
```

Comment: Hola @julitree vaya no tenia ni idea de que window.status se hubiera deshabilitado, por lo tanto no me iba a funcionar de todas formas. Muchas gracias por ayudarme!